# Mount USB on Read-Only filesystem

Tags: mount, osx, readonly

I've got a damaged Mac filesystem, and in single-user mode the command `mount -uw /` fails (error is something like `SATA warning: Enable auto-activate failed`). However, I don't need the whole filesystem to be writable, as I am just trying to copy files from my home directory to a USB. Is there a way to mount the USB to `/Volumes` in a read-only filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a directory on a read-only filesystem. But you can mount a filesystem on any existing directory. The fact that the mount is read-only doesn't affect that, and the directory doesn't need to be empty or to have particular permissions or anything.

You can mount a filesystem on `/Volumes` itself if you're only going to mount one.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem but I'm just curious: if I ever have another USB drive, is there a way to mount it as well?

Comment: Create a directory on your USB drive (which is writable) and mount the next one there.